# How i can convert this utc to local time in php?

Tags: php

1532131481886863

I tried the code below and don't work it gives me wrong date , i think has something to do with the amount of digits

```
$epoch = 1532131481886863;
$dt = new DateTime("@$epoch");  // convert UNIX timestamp to PHP DateTime
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: "nothing works" is not a problem, it's an anecdote. **What** have you tried? Show the code you tried, what the result was, and why you think that's not what it should have been.

Comment: What does your code do? What should it do instead? What is your local time?

Comment: What does `echo PHP_INT_MAX;` give you?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that the last six digits is microseconds.
So splitting the number will give you correct date and time.

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", substr($epoch, 0,-6)); 
// Optionally you can echo the microseconds also.  
echo " " . substr($epoch, -6);
```

https://3v4l.org/QDQnc

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// Divide by 1000*1000 because given number is epoch with microseconds
// but the DateTime expects time in seconds
// By dividing we will get 1532131481.886863
// We dont need the microseconds so we cast (int) on it to get 1532131481

$epoch = (int)((1532131481886863 /1000) /1000);
$dt = new DateTime("@$epoch");  // convert UNIX timestamp to PHP DateTime
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Hi, please explain your code.  It will make your answer better in quality and help newbies in PHP.

Comment: @Nic3500 explaination has been addde :)

Comment: I would not use math to get the seconds. You are creating a float value then int cast it. We all know how well programming languages handle base 10 floats. What do you find is the benefit of this?

Comment: @Andreas I totally agree, my intention was to provide an example with minimal changes to the original code instead of rewriting it - substr would have done the job aswell, but there is an answer convering this already